# div height @ certain width

Tags: css, html, height

Is there a way to make a  div be a certain height at a certain width?

So at the 800px and up the div height will be 200px

Then at 400-799px it will be 150px etc.

Comment: You should accept @Kolink answer, if it helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use Media Queries for this. For instance, if the `div` takes up the full width of the window, you can use:

```
@media all and (min-width:800px) {
    #elem {height:200px}
}
```

You can adjust the width threshold if you know the size of the `div` relative to the window (for instance, add 20 if there are a total of 20px margin around the left and right of it)

Comment: `@media` was exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Works great I just added a few of these in, works much better than most of the JQuery solutions i've found.